# Printing .mbox files

Tags: printing, mbox

I received a CD from google containing emails that were requested. they are in .mbox format. I downloaded Windows .mbox viewer which works great for viewing but not so good for anything else. I need to be able to print the emails. How can i print the emails that will also show the header (to, from,  subject)?  Any suggestions?!?!  many thanks.

Comment: An MBOX file is just a concatenated list of messages.   Why not simply load it in your favourite text editor/office suite and use that ?

Answer (score 1):

Google for, download, install and run the open source [sylpheed](http://sylpheed.sraoss.jp) email client.  Within sylpheed:

1. It will ask you for a new account setup.  We don't need an account for this so press the *Cancel* button in the popup window and then *Yes* in the next popup window to confirm.
2. From the toolbar at top, choose *File | Folder | Create new folder* and enter a name for the new folder. For example, you could try *test* (just a single word).  This is where the mbox emails will go.
3. From the toolbar at top choose *File | Import* .  In the *Source* box of the popup window enter the location of the mbox file on your computer and in the *Destination* box enter the folder name created in (2).  Press *OK*.
4. Click on the name of the created folder in the left hand column.
5. From the main window select the emails to print -- ctrl-a will select them all.  Right click any of the selected emails and choose *Print*.

**Notes:**

The selected emails are all printed to a single PDF file.

The emails I needed to print did not have attachements and I have not checked whether attachments are printed or not.

[Other email clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients) could be used in place of sylpheed but of the ones I tried I found sylpheed to be the most straight-forward for this purpose.  It directly imports mbox files, it does not force you to create an account, it does not require an add-on and Import is right on the File menu of the toolbar.

Comment: Straight-forward as promised, thank you. The only drawback for my use-case: I prefer that each mail is in a separate PDF file. If I’ll found some tool I’ll update this post